# JavaScript: Ingresar numero de 1 a 7 y devolver dia de la semana

Tags: javascript, html, condiciones, while

tengo que crear un programa en lenguaje javascript, que permita ingresar un numero entre 1 y 7 (validar el ingreso por medio de una función validaIngreso).

Luego ese número ingresado y validado pasarlo como parámetro a otra función denominada convierteDia, que recibirá el numero entre 1 y 7 y devolverá el nombre del día de la semana correspondiente (por ejemplo, si recibe 1 devolverá Lunes, si recibe 7 devolverá Domingo).

Ambas funciones incluirlas en un único archivo externo .js.
les dejo lo que hice:

```
<html>
      <head>
       <title>Dia de la semana </title>
       <script> src= 'Funciones.js'> </script>
      </head>
      <body>
            <script>


             var nro1;
                
                do {nro1 = parseInt(prompt( "Introduzca un numero: " , "[entre 1 y 7]")); }
                while (validaIngreso (nro1) );
             
             document.write("El dia de la semana para: " + nro1 " es: <b> " + convierteDia (nro1) );

             </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

y este el js

```
function validaIngreso (x)  {
       if (x<1 || x>7) return true;
       
       else return false;
    
    
    
  }
  
  function convierteDia  (d)  {
        
        if  (nro1 == 1) {
            return ("Lunes");
        }   
        else {
            if  (nro1 == 2) {
                return ("Martes");
            }
            else {
                if (nro1 == 3) {
                    return ("Miercoles");
                }   
                else {
                     if (nro1 == 4) {
                         return ("Jueves");
                     }
                         else {
                             if (nro1 == 5) {
                                 return ("viernes");
                             }
                                 else {
                                     if (nro1 == 6) {
                                         return ("Sabado");
                                     }
                                         else { return ("Domingo"); 
                                              }
                                     }
                            }
                    }
                }
        }
```

Como lo podria hacer porque no me funciona.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Recuerda agregar lo que trataste, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: usa un switch(n){ case 1: return 'Lunes' .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu archivo `Funciones.js` tiene varios detalles, como te comentan deberías usar preferentemente un `switch` para la función `convierteDia()` en lugar de varios `if-else`:

function convierteDia  (dia)  {

```
switch (dia) { 
    case 1: day = "Sunday"; 
    break; 
    case 2: day = "Monday"; 
    break; 
    case 3: day = "Tuesday"; 
    break; 
    case 4: day = "Wednesday"; 
    break; 
    case 5: day = "Thursday"; 
    break; 
    case 6: day = "Friday"; 
    break; 
    case 7: day = "Saturday"; 
     }

  return day;

}
```

En tu código html te falta concatenar la variable `nro1` :

```
   <html>
          <head>
           <title>Dia de la semana </title>
           <script> src= 'Funciones.js'> </script>
          </head>
          <body>
                <script>

                    var nro1;                
                    do {nro1 = parseInt(prompt( "Introduzca un numero: " , "[entre 1 y 7]")); }
                    while (validaIngreso (nro1) );
                 
                 document.write("El dia de la semana para: " + nro1 + " es: <b> " + convierteDia (nro1) );

                 </script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Revisa esta demo:

```js
    function validaIngreso (x)  {
           if (x<1 || x>7) 
           return true;       
           else 
           return false;
      }
      

    function convierteDia  (dia)  {

    switch (dia) { 
        case 1: day = "Sunday"; 
        break; 
        case 2: day = "Monday"; 
        break; 
        case 3: day = "Tuesday"; 
        break; 
        case 4: day = "Wednesday"; 
        break; 
        case 5: day = "Thursday"; 
        break; 
        case 6: day = "Friday"; 
        break; 
        case 7: day = "Saturday"; 
         }

      return day;

    }

           </script>
          </head>
          <body>
                <script>

 var nro1;                
                    do {nro1 = parseInt(prompt( "Introduzca un numero: " , "[entre 1 y 7]")); }
                    while (validaIngreso (nro1) );
                 
                 document.write("El dia de la semana para: " + nro1 + " es: <b> " + convierteDia (nro1) );

                 </script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Espero te pueda ayudar este ejemplo. La razón por la que no funciona tu código es por los paréntesis después de return

switch (Numero) {
case 0:
day = "Sunday";
break;
case 1:
day = "Monday";
break;
case 2:
day = "Tuesday";
break;
case 3:
day = "Wednesday";
break;
case 4:
day = "Thursday";
break;
case 5:
day = "Friday";
break;
case 6:
day = "Saturday";
}

Comment: en vez de cada break solo debería hacer un return del día correspondiente Ejem: `case 1: return "Lunes";`